# Quarkus Event bus is not working when deployed in OpenShift cluster but it works perfectly in local developer machine

Tags: quarkus, vertx-eventbus

I am publishing event and consuming event in the same Quarkus application. Earlier it used to work but recently it stop working, not sure of the cause why it stopped working. Here is the code sample.

```java
import io.quarkus.vertx.ConsumeEvent;
import io.smallrye.common.annotation.Blocking;
import jakarta.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import jakarta.inject.Inject;

@ApplicationScoped
public class Consumer {

    @Inject
    Logger log;

    @ConsumeEvent(value = "excelRow", blocking = true)
    public void excelRow(RowData rowData) {
        log.info("Inside Excel row even bus");
    }
}
```

```java
import io.vertx.mutiny.core.eventbus.EventBus;


public class EventProducer {

    Logger log = Logger.getLogger(EventProducer.class);
    private EventBus bus;

    public void setEventBus(EventBus bus) {
        this.bus = bus;
    }

    public void processRowData(Map<String, String> rowValues) {
        log.info("Reading a row complete, calling excelRow even bus");
        bus.publish("excelRow", rowData);
    }
}
```

This same code is working in local but not in OpenShift clusters, I have no idea on what to do to resolved this issue. Not configuration had be set for event bus.

Comment: Are you using a clustered event bus? The cluster event bus is not supported in Kubernetes/OpenShift.

Comment: I am not using the clustered event bus. Thank for response.

I have found the issue any way. The reason is because of Quarkus Even bus.

Reference: https://quarkus.io/guides/vertx-reference

Configuration: quarkus.vertx.event-loops-pool-size

The number of event loops. By default, it matches the number of CPUs detected on the system.

Once the above configuration is added it started working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reference Quarkus vertx guide: quarkus.io/guides/vertx-reference

Configuration: quarkus.vertx.event-loops-pool-size
This configuration is for quarkus even bus. The number of event loops. By default, it matches the number of CPUs detected on the system.

Once the above configuration is added it started working.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tqe3.png)

Comment: How many CPU cores did you have? Overcommitting on the number of event loops is rarely a good idea.

Comment: I am using Apple M1 which is supposed to have 8 CPU cores.

Comment: After incrementing this, the initial issue solved with event bus hanging... when I just added 5. But now the problem is I am getting mutiny timeout when calling redis set or get also calling the methods inside uni or multi calls are not happening. Tool just hangs in there.
Any idea on this? @Clement

Comment: I think something is wrong elsewhere. Could you open an issue with a reproducer? I guess that you are blocking the event loop somewhere.

Comment: We also have Redis connection along with it. We have made the changes from io.quarkus redis library to Jedis library, which is working fine now. We are able to do the stress test as well.

Comment: I believe you hit the unpooled Redis connection bug we are fixing at the moment. We do not recommend Jedis in a Quarkus app.